# How to mitigate OAuth issue where refresh token request is abandoned by client but not server?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a web application written that uses the OAuth "authorization code" grant type to retrieve the initial access token, and then the "refresh token" grant type to refresh the access token on occasion.

However, a problem occurs when the OAuth server is bogged down and the request for a refresh token takes long (10+ seconds). The client will timeout the request and cancel it, but the server fulfills the request eventually. When the server fulfills the request, it generates the new access token and refresh token and simultaneously invalidates the old refresh token. The client never receives the new tokens.

Now the next time the client tries to renew it's token again (when the server is not bogged down), it's attempting to do so with an invalid (old) refresh token. Now the only way to fix the problem is to use the "authorization code" grant again, which requires manual intervention by the end user.

How do others work around this issue?

Comment: Maybe a silly though: can you wait longer than 10 seconds? If not, do you control the server? Maybe the server can cancel the process.

Comment: Yes, the organization I work for runs the server, and we're trying to figure out why it takes that long sometimes. But I think there will always be the potential for this problem.

Comment: Personally I would take this as an infrastructure bug, because 10 seconds is a low timeout. Some servers create small windows in which the old refresh token remains valid, but if you have 0 control and this happens re-authenticating is the 'sane' option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the exact same issue at a company I worked at.

The advice I gave them is not to expire/rotate refresh tokens.  The Oauth protocol allows for refresh token rotation, but does not require it.  In the [Oauth threat model](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.2.3), the value and the implications are discussed, including the following note:

> Note: This measure may cause problems in clustered environments,
> since usage of the currently valid refresh token must be ensured.  In
> such an environment, other measures might be more appropriate.

The case you are dealing with is another reason (in addition to the note above) on why refresh token expiry is not a great idea.

If you have no control over that, then you have to develop some duct-tape kludge solution where you retain refresh tokens and substitute on the server side an expired refresh token for a current one.  It's ugly, very ugly, but unfortunately I'm not sure there is much more you can do with this painful security control that causes more problems than what it is worth.